# Testing With A Fake DbContext and Autofixture and Moq

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit, moq, autofixture

SO follow this example

[example](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/) and how make a fake DBContex For test my test using just this work fine

```
[Test]
public void CiudadIndex()
{
    var ciudades = new FakeDbSet<Ciudad>
    {
        new Ciudad {CiudadId = 1, EmpresaId =1, Descripcion ="Santa Cruz", FechaProceso = DateTime.Now, MarcaBaja = null, UsuarioId = 1},
        new Ciudad {CiudadId = 2, EmpresaId =1, Descripcion ="La Paz", FechaProceso = DateTime.Now, MarcaBaja = null, UsuarioId = 1},
        new Ciudad {CiudadId = 3, EmpresaId =1, Descripcion ="Cochabamba", FechaProceso = DateTime.Now, MarcaBaja = null, UsuarioId = 1}
    };

    //// Create mock unit of work
    var mockData = new Mock<IContext>();
    mockData.Setup(m => m.Ciudades).Returns(ciudades);

    // Setup controller
    var homeController = new CiudadController(mockData.Object);

    // Invoke
    var viewResult = homeController.Index();
    var ciudades_de_la_vista = (IEnumerable<Ciudad>)viewResult.Model;

    // Assert..
}
```

Iam tryign now to use Autofixture-Moq

to create "ciudades" but I cant. I try this

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var ciudades = fixture.Build<FakeDbSet<Ciudad>>().CreateMany<FakeDbSet<Ciudad>>();
var mockData = new Mock<IContext>();
mockData.Setup(m => m.Ciudades).Returns(ciudades);
```

I get this error

> Cant convert  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(FakeDbSet(Ciudad)) to System.Data.Entity.IDbSet(Ciudad)

cant put "<>" so I replace with "()" in the error message

Implementation of IContext and  FakeDbSet

```
public interface IContext
{
    IDbSet<Ciudad> Ciudades { get; }
}
public class FakeDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T> where T : class
```

how can make this to work?

Comment: What version of AutoFixture?

Comment: @Diego_DB that means there def should be no reason to restate the type args in your `CreateMany` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minor point... In stuff like:

```
var ciudades_fixture = fixture.Build<Ciudad>().CreateMany<Ciudad>();
```

The second type arg is unnecessary and should be:

```
var ciudades_fixture = fixture.Build<Ciudad>().CreateMany();
```

I really understand why you need a `FakeDbSet` and the article is a bit TL;DR... In general, I try to avoid faking and mucking with ORM bits and instead dealing with interfaces returning POCOs to the max degree possible.

That aside... The reason the normal syntax for initialising the list works is that there is an `Add` (and `IEnumerable`) in DBFixture. AutoFixture doesn't have a story for that pattern directly (after all it is compiler syntactic sugar and not particularly amenable to reflection or in line with any other conventions) but you can use `AddManyTo` as long as there is an `ICollection` in play. Luckily, within the impl of `FakeDbSet` as in the article, the following gives us an in:-

```
public ObservableCollection<T> Local
{
    get { return _data; }
}
```

As `ObservableCollection<T>` derives from `ICollection<T>`, you should be able to:

```
var ciudades = new FakeDbSet<Cuidad>();
fixture.AddManyTo(ciudades.Local);

var mockData = new Mock<IContext>();
mockData.Setup(m => m.Ciudades).Returns(ciudades);
```

It's possible to wire up a customization to make this prettier, but at least you have a way to manage it. The other option is to have something implement ICollection (or add a prop *with a setter* taking `IEnumerable<T>` and have AF generate the parent object, causing said collection to be filled in.

---

Long superseded side note: In your initial question, you effectively have:

```
fixture.Build<FakeDbSet<Ciudad>>().CreateMany()
```

The problem becomes clearer then - you are asking AF to generate *Many* `FakeDbSet<Ciudad>`s, which is not what you want.

Comment: I try to avoid faking and mucking with ORM bits and instead dealing with interfaces returning POCOs to the max degree possible.

do you have any example for that?. Iam new in test,mock,Di and all this thing talking here

Comment: @Diego_DX Depends what you're doing way too much. one case is I'd be having my Controller talk to something that returns `T[]` instead of having to stuff things into a `X<T>` only to then turn around and ask it for all of the stuff I fed in - in general I'd focus on figuring out how one thing talks to the outside world at a time. But that's just generalities. May I strongly recommend Mark Seemann's two courses on PluralSight ? Esp the Advanced Unit testing might be a bit of a stretch depending on where you're starting but there's a lot of insight in all his work (and it's not TL;DR articles!)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used AutoFixture in a while, but shouldn't it be:

```
var ciudades = new FakeDbSet<Ciudad>();
fixture.AddManyTo(ciudades);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the moment I end doing this, I will keep reading about how use automoq, cause I'm new in this

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var ciudades_fixture = fixture.Build<Ciudad>().CreateMany<Ciudad>();
var ciudades = new FakeDbSet<Ciudad>();
foreach (var item in ciudades_fixture)
{
    ciudades.Add(item);
}
var mockData = new Mock<IContext>(); 
fixture.Create<Mock<IContext>>();
mockData.Setup(r => r.Ciudades).Returns(ciudades);
```

Comment: AutoMoq is just adding more techy mess here - e.g. `fixture.Create<Mock<IContext>>()` doesn't have any side effects whatsoever;
. AddManyTo is the real answer but the FakeDbSet doesnt directly allow it as discussed in my answer. having said that, functionally it's achieving the same as lines 2-7 above, and you could extract that to a generic extension method quite easily.