# How to mockup Entity Framework 6 With Moq & Autofixture

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, moq, autofixture

I am using [AutoMoq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) but I am kinda confused how to write my first unit test because of Entity Framework's (using EF6 and code first) `dbContext`

```
// in service class(constructor)
private readonly MyContext context;

public PriceService(MyContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

// following would be in nunit test method.
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
var priceService = fixture.Create<PriceService>();
```

When I run the unit test it crashes

```
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.AutoPropertiesCommand`1.Execute(Object specimen, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.MethodInvoker.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.c__DisplayClass6.b__1(ISpecimenBuilder b)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a5`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.Create[T](ISpecimenContext context, T seed)
    at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.Create[T](ISpecimenContext context)
    at PriceServiceTests.Test_Price_Object_Setup() in PriceServiceTests.cs:line 26
```

Edit

In EF 6 seems like they are making the DbSet more mockable.

[https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20May%2016%2c%202013](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20May%2016,%202013)

> Make DbSet more mockable
>
> - These means adding a protected constructor and making methods virtual
> - Note that a type derived from DbSet that uses the protected constructor would create an object not be bound to any context and the methods would be no-ops. This makes it very like IDbSet from the perspective of creating test doubles.
> - If we took this option we could potentially obsolete IDbSet
> - It’s worth noting that no cases have been identified where this would be functionally different to using IDbSet for test doubles. However, there is strong feeling in the community that interfaces are preferred.

Anyone know how to mock it up?

Edit 2

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) but it keeps crashing

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //public GroceryListContext()
    //    : base()
    //{

    //}
    public virtual DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Test_Price_Object_Setup_Properly()
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<MyContext>();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Price>>(); // had to add EF to my test solution.
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Prices).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    var service = new PriceService(mockContext.Object);

    // dies when using autofixture so thought try first moq like in article
   //var priceService = fixture.Create<PriceService>();

   Assert.That(true, Is.EqualTo(false));
}
```

with the following exception:

> MyContext.Tests.Services.PriceServiceTests.Test_If_Price_Object_Setup_Properly:  `System.ArgumentException : Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.    ----> System.TypeLoadException : Method 'Create' on type 'DbSet`1Proxyb409fc6b430b4568aac048b60ea2f02e' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' tried to implicitly override a method with weaker type parameter constraints`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696777/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext-and-autofixture-and-moq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391146/using-autofixture-in-my-data-integration-tests-to-create-proxies and https://autofixture.codeplex.com/discussions/262557 Question: Have you isolated that EF6 is actually behaving differently to 5 or are you just trying to be complete?

Comment: The last example you provided, the one without AutoFixture works on my machine. I have copied your PriceService, MyContext classes and Test_Price_Object_Setup_Properly method. I implemented my own Price class as you didn't provide that and it runs without any exception. I am using Entity Framework 6.0 RC 1 and Visual Studio 2013 RC.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Well my question started out of how to just mockout the Datacontext then I found that EF can do mocking on the dbset and does not need a wrapper. I ran into huge problems while do the tutorial. I know now it is autofixture that was the problem, It installs version 3.0 of moq but 4.0 is needed for the tutorial to work. I am not sure if it is possible to use autofixture now because of this.

Comment: @OlavNybø - Ya it works on my machine now as you probably just installed moq straight from it's nuget package. I got it from autofixture and that installs version 3 and you need moq version 4 for that piece of code to work.

Comment: @chobo Good that you have it working now and obv not good it cost you time to get there. In general AutoFixture depends on the earliest version that **it** needs to pass its tests. If you need Moq v4 because you have a library with a wierd dependency. Should AutoFixture.Xunit require 1.9.2 because 1.8 doesn't work well with Tech Z ? IOW I think it's important and useful that AF doesnt force dependencies on stuff that's not absolutely necessary (for example the 3.0+ dep on .NET 4 caused me a almost a day's yak shaving recently - but I had a chance to vote on whether the dep was OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a [specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) which indicates that the `DbSet<T>` class should be mocked (although it's not an abstract type or interface).

The reason for that is because the `DbSet<T>` class is public but it has a *protected* constructor.

**Specification**:

```
internal class DbSetTypeSpecification : IRequestSpecification
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
    {
        var type = request as Type;
        if (type == null)
            return false;

        return type.IsGenericType
            && typeof(DbSet<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    }
}
```

**Example**:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(
        new MockRelay(
            new DbSetTypeSpecification()));

    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => 
        fixture.Create<PriceService>());
}
```

Now AutoFixture can provide auto-generated `PriceService` values.

---

Please note that the `MyContext` class is also public and, AFAICT, it has a public constructor too. This means that AutoFixture will not supply an auto-mocked instance for `MyContext` class by default.

(If you can provide your scenario I might be able to help further.)

Comment: Have you tried this against EF 6? I found out that the reason why nothing was working for me was AutoFixture installed moq 3 and I needed moq 4 for the tutorial to work. I tried to keep moq 4 and autofixture but then I never could import the Fixture "using".

Comment: Well I am just looking into Autofixture never really used it before. I want to setup my tests so I don't have to create all the mocks(with moq) and dummy data by hand. That is what I am trying to do. I am also a bit unclear when I need certain data in my mock to be a certain value(say the price in the PriceObject must be 5).

Comment: @chobo2 About Moq please read my answer [here](https://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4260).

Comment: Nikos, you've earned a +1 from me even if others are more precious with their clicks :) @chobo2 NB make sure you look at the various SO Q & As re generating test data being returned over Moqed interfaces (Moq essentially doesn't provide a way to globally hook return value generation so you'll need to understand when/how/where you can feed in appropriate customizations per test). (Many of those posts generally have EF involved - it often makes people stop thinking what's doing to isolate issues. It's critical to be sure tests are failing for the right reason at all times - esp with automocking)

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis - Yep I saw your post, I figured out why it was not working for me. I told nuget to not get dependencies and that included Autofixture so it only got AutoFixture.moq so that's why namepsaces where not importing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NuGet Package called `AutoFixture.AutoEF` which may solve your issue

```
fixture.Customize(new EntityCustomization(new DbContextEntityTypesProvider(typeof(MyContext))));
```